# how to change the comma (,) to centerdot (\cdot) through the \active command (\catcode`\,=13)?

Tags: macros, tex-core, catcodes

I want to modify the catcode of comma, with the following code

\catcode`\,=13
\def,{$\cdot$}

I get the following error message:

```
 ! Missing control sequence inserted.
    <inserted text> 
                    \inaccessible 
    l.43 \printkeywords
```

how to change the input comma to output \cdot in the particular environment?

below is the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{gray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.3}
\newbox\keybox
\newbox\tempbox
\newdimen\tempdima

\newenvironment{keywords}{\global\setbox\keybox\vbox\bgroup}{\egroup}

\def\printkeywords{\par%
                    \setbox\tempbox\hbox{Keywords}%Zusammenfassung
                        \tempdima\wd\tempbox%
                        \advance\tempdima4.2mm%
                        \advance\tempdima4.2mm%
                        \noindent\fboxsep0pt\colorbox{gray}{\vbox to 13pt{\hsize\tempdima\vfill\noindent\hspace*{4.2mm}Keywords\vfill}}
                         \endgraf\vspace*{2.8pt}%
                         {\catcode`\,=13
                         \def,{$\cdot$}
                         \noindent\ignorespaces\unvcopy\keybox\endgraf}
                 }




\begin{keywords}
Keyword 1, Keyword 1, Keyword 2
\end{keywords}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

Text, Text, Text, Text, 


\section{Section 1}

\printkeywords


\section{Section 2}

\printkeywords
```

Comment: you are just showing the output of a box`\unvcopy\keybox` (which would be better as `\usebox` in latex) so no macros are expanded and no catcodes are looked up, the content has already been typeset _before_ it was saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your attempt:

1. when you do `\setbox\keybox=\vbox{...}`, the text is already typeset and changing the category code of `,` at time of printing will do nothing
2. the category code of `,` when the definition of `\printkeywords` is absorbed is 12, so you can't do `\def,{$\cdot$}`.

You have to change the category code in the `keywords` environment.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{gray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.3}
\newbox\keybox
\newbox\tempbox
\newdimen\tempdima

\newenvironment{keywords}{\global\setbox\keybox\vbox\bgroup
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`, \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{${}\cdot{}$\ignorespaces}%
  \catcode`,=\active
}{\egroup}

\def\printkeywords{\par%
                    \setbox\tempbox\hbox{Keywords}%Zusammenfassung
                        \tempdima\wd\tempbox%
                        \advance\tempdima4.2mm%
                        \advance\tempdima4.2mm%
                        \noindent\fboxsep0pt\colorbox{gray}{\vbox to 13pt{\hsize\tempdima\vfill\noindent\hspace*{4.2mm}Keywords\vfill}}
                         \endgraf\vspace*{2.8pt}%
                         \noindent\ignorespaces\unvcopy\keybox\endgraf
                 }




\begin{keywords}
Keyword 1, Keyword 1, Keyword 2
\end{keywords}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

Text, Text, Text, Text, 


\section{Section 1}

\printkeywords

\end{document}
```

A different implementation:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xparse}

\definecolor{vgray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\keywords}{m}
 {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_venkatesan_keywords_clist { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printkeywords}{}
 {
  \par\noindent
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}
  \colorbox{vgray}{\,Keywords\,}
  \group_end:
  \\*[3pt]
  \clist_use:Nn \g_venkatesan_keywords_clist { ${}\cdot{}$ }
  \par
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\keywords{Keyword 1, Keyword 1, Keyword 2}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

Text, Text, Text, Text, 

\section{Section 1}

\printkeywords

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll add later a possibly better implementation

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{environ}

\newenviron{keywords}{%
  <Do whatever you want>
  \processkeywords{\BODY}
  ...
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \processkeywords { O{\ $\cdot$\ } m }
 {
  \clist_set:NV \l_tmpa_clist { #2 }
  \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```